# No left border to the right of certain class

Tags: css, border

Is there any way to specify with CSS to disable a left-border to the right of a cell with a certain class?

As you can see in this image the border to the right is double, it has the border of class "selected" plus the default gray  border. I want the "selected" cell's right border to override the neighboring cell's left-border somehow.

FWIW, I think this is because of the table's CSS where I have commented 'border-collapse'. I need to do this otherwise I can't have rounded corner's on the table.

[image]

```
.ui-tabs-panel td {   /*  default table cell */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E9EBDF;
    border-left: 1px solid #E9EBDF;
    padding: 7px 7px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #FAFDFF;
}

.ui-tabs-panel td.selected {  /* when selected */
    border-right: 1px solid #94DFEB !important;
    border-left: 1px double #94DFEB !important;

    background-color: #FFF !important;
    color: #087DBD;
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML and CSS look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, the current extra border belongs to the next `<td>` element, Try this to clear the border:

```
.ui-tabs-panel td.selected + td {
    border-left: none;
}
```

You can select the next sibling element by **[Adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)**

`element1 + element2` Selects every `element2` element that are placed immediately after `element1` element(s). They're *siblings*.

Comment: Genious! Didn't know about the `<next element>` syntax with a plus sign. Thanks so much.